# Comparing PRAM and Circuit Complexity, $NC^i$

Tags: complexity-theory, parallel-computing, circuits

I wondered about the following quote from [NC (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)#The_NC_hierarchy):

> $NC^i$ is the class of decision problems decidable by uniform boolean circuits with a polynomial number of gates of at most two inputs and depth $O(\log^i n)$, or the class of decision problems solvable in time $O(\log^i n)$ on a parallel computer with a polynomial number of processors.

Are these classes actually the same?

Looking at the proofsketch of Lemma 2.4.2 in [Limits to Parallel Computation](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Eruzzo/papers/limits.pdf), we have a logarithmic depth overhead when converting from the PRAM model to a circuit.
The reason seems to be a uniform cost measure for the PRAMs operations.
Hence, I would expect $NC^{i + 1}$ to be the class of decision problems solvable in time $O(\log^i n)$ (uniform cost measure) on a parallel computer with a polynomial number of processors.

If the classes are different, does the additional requirement of a logarithmic cost measure fix this?